# Updating OpenSSL version on OSX

Tags: macos, openssl, osx-lion

Currently on OSX 10.7 Lion openssl 0.9.8r is installed. This build is from Feb 2011 and I want to update it to the newest version. I can't use the autoupdate because I need the enable-cms option so I built it from the source, run `./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc`and `./config enable-cms --openssldir=~/usr/local/ssl`.
Then I made "make" and "make install" without any errors but there is still the old version installed.

```
> openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe it's the folder? I only guessed that the `ssl` folder in `/usr/local/` must be the default open ssl installation directory from Mac OSX?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin, it refers to `/usr/bin/openssl/`... but when I set `./config --openssldir=/usr/bin/opennssl` then it will copy all openssl files in there? But there should only be an executable?

Comment: check here: http://techscienceinterest.blogspot.com/2010/12/compiling-openssl-on-mac-os-x-snow.html worked perfectly work me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution.

Before starting:

1. download sources
2. unpack sources
3. go into the unpacked source directory

The *prefix* has to be set on the `/usr/` folder.

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/ darwin64-x86_64-cc enable-cms
sudo make
sudo make install
```

**Note**: To perform just a normal update you can drop the `enable-cms` option.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Still the old version. And ./configure wont build. I had to use ./config for the 32 bit version. 64 bits wont work.

Comment: Could you give me a little bit more information or start a new question? Which OSX version, openssl version, further build targets and so on would be interested.

Comment: Steps worked for me after doing 'make clean', because I'd already configure the build wrongly before.

Comment: This does not work for me. In which directory are you executing these commands, and are you sure this is for OSX?

Comment: Ah. The answer is missing steps: 1. download sources, 2. unpack sources, 3. go into the unpacked source directory. 4. execute commands in this answer.

Comment: Thanks Rolf for pointing this out. I've added it to the original answer.

Comment: Worked for me, but the system suggested configure is ./Configure. if I use lower case, it would suggest ./config and the configure was not successful when used ./config. By the way, I am using the OS X El Capitan

Answer (score 1):

brew version (installed in '/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin') has such support for me.

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openssl@1.1